# How to pass inputs to a shell script in automator?

Tags: automator, services

I want to pass the filename of the file I rightclicked to a shell script through automator:

```
# encrypt file.txt to file.enc using 256-bit AES in CBC mode
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.txt.enc
```

When I create a 'service' I can pass on the input 'as arguments', but how to I implement it in the code?
It would be great if the file could be called 'file.enc' instead of 'file.txt.enc' if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pass=$(osascript -e 'tell app (path to frontmost application as text)
text returned of (display dialog "Enter password:" default answer "")
end')
for f in "$@"; do
    printf %s "$pass" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in "$f" -out "${f%.*}.enc" -pass stdin
done
```

Comment: could you explain your code a little? And maybe submit a decrypt option :)

Comment: You can [pass variables as input](http://coreygilmore.com/blog/2010/05/07/passing-multiple-automator-variables-to-a-shell-script/), but not both files and variables, so I used AppleScript for displaying the dialog. You can decrypt the files with `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in file.enc -out file.txt`. `${f%x*}` deletes the shortest `x*` pattern from the end, like `xcc` in `aaxbbxcc`. `for f in "$@"` is the common way to loop through arguments: `for f in "$*"` and `for f in $@` are often errors.

Comment: I can't recall how many problems I've had to fix due to an un-quoted `$@` in for loops. Knowing when and which quotes to use is not an easy thing.